# Errors in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Greet from './components/Greet'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Greet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the code in App.js. I have made an other file of greet to run it and display the name.
This is the Greet.js code

```
import React from 'react'
function Greet(){
    return <h1> Hello Nabeel </h1>
}

export default App;
```

### There are 1 warring and 2 errors.
-src\App.js
Line 3:8:  'Greet' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
-src\components\Greet.js
Line 2:10:  'Greet' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 12:33-36
export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App' (module has no exports)

ERROR in [eslint]
src\components\Greet.js
  Line 6:16:  'App' is not defined  no-undef
```

What i should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The Error message is already obvious, please remember to define your function.

Greet.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Greet(){
    return <h1> Hello Nabeel </h1>
}

export default Greet;
```